# Where to find "sleep mode" drivers for debian distro?

Tags: drivers, debian, sleep, hp-pavilion, crunchbang

I have HP pavillion g6 dualbooted, running windows 7 and crunchbanng 11, 64 bit, based on debian wheezy.

My crunchbang won't wake from sleep mode, I had similar problem on windows 7, solved the issue by [downloading drivers from HP site](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5078476#N2528) (downloaded them all), but i can't seem to find these on the official HP site for debian.

Some people say that i need to remove `nomodeset` but crunchbang won't boot if i do so.

I have a [CD containing drivers for debian firmware](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/), I downloaded it from Debian website, solved the bluetooth problem using it, but i can't seem to find the right driver for sleep mode.

Here's  all the info you need to know about my graphic card

[image]